# Delete all documents matching a query?

Tags: xquery, marklogic

I would like to delete all documents matching some predicates. The query I have come up with is as follows, but nothing is deleted from the database.

I suspect this is because the $doc is set to the XML value of the document rather than the document itself. Can anyone shed any light on this?

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
for $doc in cts:search(fn:collection("MYCOLLECTIONNAME")/MyDocumentRoot,
    cts:or-query((
    cts:element-range-query (xs:QName("MyElement"), "=", "MyElementValue"),
    )), "unfiltered" )
    return xdmp:document-delete($doc);
```

The document looks like

```
<MyDocumentRoot>
  <MyElementName>MyElementValue</MyElementName>
</MyDocumentRoot>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are indeed passing the contents of the documents into xdmp:document-delete instead of its uri. You could derive the uri using for instance `fn:base-uri()`, but like this all docs you want to delete are retrieved from the database first, which is unnecessary.

Instead, enable the URI lexicon, and use `cts:uris` to do the deletion. It might also be wise to do the deletion in batches of lets say 1000 docs.

HTH!

Comment: Totally spot on about using the URI as well as batching.

Comment: Watch out for `xml:base` attributes with `fn:base-uri`! Most of the time it's safer to use `xdmp:node-uri`.

Comment: `xml:base` isn't used that often, but yes `xdmp:node-uri` is probably safer if you are not sure there won't be xml:base attributes that could mess things up. There is also `fn:document-uri`, but that explicitly only works on document nodes, so you would combine that with 'fn:root' unless you are sure you have doc nodes at hand. Then again xdmp:node-uri is a short hand for exactly that..

Answer (score 4):

`xdmp:document-delete()` takes the URI of the document, rather than a node. So the simplest fix would be to wrap `$doc` in `base-uri(.)`:

```
return xdmp:document-delete(base-uri($doc))
```

But if you have the URI lexicon enabled, you can write a much faster query like this:

```
let $query := cts:and-query((
                cts:collection-query("MYCOLLECTIONNAME"),
                cts:or-query((...)) (: put your full or query here :)
              ))
for $uri in cts:uris("",(),$query) return xdmp:document-delete($uri)
```

In the latter case, you avoid having to read each document to get its URI.

Answer (score 3):

`xdmp:collection-delete("MYCOLLECTIONNAME")` is also worth a mention.

Answer (score 0):

On the last line, change to

```
xdmp:document-delete(fn:base-uri($doc));
```

Comment: Watch out for `xml:base` attributes with `fn:base-uri`! Most of the time it's safer to use `xdmp:node-uri`.